# how to show last canvas image

Tags: php, jquery

im trying to find a way to only show las signature created in canvas, but the problem is that senes the img don't save in the DB i cant limit 1; like in mysqli_query or can you??

This is where the signature is created.

```
<div id="signArea" >
    <h2 class="tag-ingo">Put signature below,</h2>
    <div class="sig sigWrapper" style="height:auto;">
        <div class="typed"></div>
        <canvas class="sign-pad" id="sign-pad" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btnSaveSign">Save Signature</button>
```

when the signature is created it call this function which saves the signature to a file  :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signArea').signaturePad({drawOnly:true, 
        drawBezierCurves:true, lineTop:90});
});

$("#btnSaveSign").click(function(e) { 
   html2canvas([document.getElementById('sign-pad')], {
       onrendered: function (canvas) { 
           var canvas_img_data =canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
           var img_data = canvas_img_data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
           //ajax call to save image inside folder
           $.ajax({
               url: 'save_sign.php',
               data: { img_data:img_data },
               type: 'post',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (response) {
                   window.location.reload();
               }
           });
        }
    });
});
```

save_sign.php

```
<?php 
$result = array();
$imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['img_data']);
$filename = md5(date("dmYhisA"));
//Location to where you want to created sign image
$file_name = 'doc_signs/'.$filename.'.png';
file_put_contents($file_name,$imagedata);
$result['status'] = 1;
$result['file_name'] = $file_name;
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

The output loads like this:

```
<?php
$image_list = glob("doc_signs/*.png");
foreach($image_list as $image){ 
?>
```

my problem is that it loads all images saved in the file , is there any whay to ony load last image and reset on load page??? .

Comment: Please format the code in the question properly by using some sensible indention. It's currently very hard to read and follow the flow of the code since the indention seem pretty inconsistent and random.

Comment: You should also include _all_ the relevant code. What does `save_sign.php` contain? Are you just saving the files on the server? Please include a proper _explanation_ of what your code actually does. Also, a question to the people that upvoted this question... why? It's incomplete...

Comment: We can't answer your question without understanding how you save the data in the first place.

Comment: i added save_sign.php contain

Comment: Ok. so 1) if you gave your filenames a timestamp when you save them, it would be easier to find the most recently added one when the page is reloaded. 2) you could consider saving the name of the the most recently added one in another file (or even - in a database!! SQLite is easy to set up...) so you can always refer to that record whenever you load the page.

Comment: 3) As a side issue, what is the point of using AJAX if you're just going to do `window.location.reload()` as soon as the AJAX call finishes? You might as well have submitted the data via a normal postback in the first place, and saved a HTTP request. The whole point of AJAX is to prevent you having to reload the whole page! I can't see a reason why you would need to refresh anything after that save operation anyway...